# Why does Python not protect against global scope variable in local functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not understand the benefit of allowing variables defined in the global scope to be accessible to local functions unless explicitly defined. It seems that this may introduce some hard to track error when naming conventions are similar due to the nature of the problem and wouldn't it be clearer to everyone if the global variable is only available to local function scope if it is explicitly defined to be so?

Example code (made simple):

```
def train(acc):
    acc += 1
    return acc

def infer(acc):
    acc += 2
    return accuracy


accuracy  = train(1)
accuracy2 = infer(5)

print("train",accuracy,"inference",accuracy2)
```

Actual python return >>> `train 2 inference 2`

Expected return as of personal opinion >>>  `Error: Function infer() does not have variable named accuracy`

This "error" arises as the user mistakenly return `accuracy`(from the global scope) in `infer()` and not `acc` which is in the local function scope variable. This happened to me recently as I was copying over large chunks of codes and I forgot to change the return variable name in the function. Unfortunately, there was a variable with the same name in the global scope!

Why doesn't Python force the user to explicitly defined global variables in functions so that everyone is clear on the intention of actually using the global variable? Example:

```
def train(acc):
    acc += 1
    return acc

def infer(acc):
    global accuracy
    acc = accuracy + acc
    return acc

accuracy  = train(1)
accuracy2 = infer(5)

print(accuracy,accuracy2) >>> 2 7
```

The code examples given are overly simplified for the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: Because if it did, there would be no way to use global names, or maybe `return` would have to be special cased, and in special cases lay madness.

Comment: I think IDEs and linters could help you with avoiding this, anyway.

Comment: This is not the right place to complain about or challenge programming language design decisions. But in general the design of Python allows you to shoot yourself in the foot, it just expects from you to be smart enough not to do it.

Comment: It is not `user mistakenly return accuracy`, it is the programmer. Anyway, in this case python can detect that mistake and give you an error. This way, the programmer can see the error when they run their unit tests.

Comment: You could just as easily ask why Python lets you create local variables by accident. One typo and you end up silently assigning to some new variable that never should have existed. Why not require an explicit `local` declaration for all local variables to prevent this? There's a tradeoff between safety and brevity. Python picked brevity here.

Comment: Adding on due to comments, I am not complaining about this "feature" but I am more curious about the WHY part of the question. There must be a reason why Python allows global scope variables into individual function's local scope, like what kind of brevity/convenience does this provide?

Comment: If you were to transfer all your functions into another .py files to form a module to be imported by your main file (__main__ == True), all of the global variables in the module script is then completely ignored. Is this an inconsistent practice or am I missing out on something?

Comment: These issues are faced by all programming languages and each one chooses from a few options about what the rules are.

Comment: See [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: You should ask on python-list, the forum for Python language design.